# AWK command to get distinct values in a column based on the values in another column that are the same

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I want to find rows that have the same values in col1 and col2, and get their distinct third column

Say I have this data

```
City,Sunset,Anna
City,Sunset,Anna
City,Sunset,Ben
City,Sunset,Ben
```

My desired output is:

```
City,Sunset,"Anna,Ben"
```

So far, I have this code

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/,/|/2' | awk -F"," '{if (!($1 in a)) a[$1] = $2; else a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2 } END { for (key in a) print key, a[key] }' OFS=,
```

But Im only getting

```
City,Sunset,Anna,Anna,Ben,Ben
```

When the output should be

```
City,Sunset,"Anna,Ben"
```

Could someone help me with this one?

Comment: If your real data doesn't always have the same values in the first 2 fields then you should provide sample input/output that doesn't always have the same values in the first 2 fields. A potential solution tested with your current sample input could produce the expected output but be completely wrong in how it handles differences in the first 2 fields.

Comment: The script in your question cannot produce the output you say it does from the input you show - please correct your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    key = $1 FS $2
    val = $3
}
key != prev {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print prev, "\"" vals "\""
    }
    vals = sep = ""
    prev = key
    delete seen
}
!seen[val]++ {
    vals = vals sep val
    sep = OFS
}
END {
    print prev, "\"" vals "\""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
City,Sunset,"Anna,Ben"
```

That will work if you have multiple different values in the first 2 input fields, and regardless of the order of the 3rd field values.

It will output values in the order they appear in the input and only stores the values for one key pair at a time rather than storing the whole file.

For example, given this input:

```
$ cat file
City,Sunset,Anna
City,Sunset,Ben
City,Sunset,Sue
City,Sunset,Ben
Town,Sunrise,Ben
Town,Sunrise,Phil
```

it will produce what I assume is the expected output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
City,Sunset,"Anna,Ben,Sue"
Town,Sunrise,"Ben,Phil"
```

The above script assumes your input is grouped by the values of the first 2 fields, if it isn't then run `sort -t, -k1,2` on it first.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` (for multi-dimensional arrays, output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
awk -F, '{ arr[$1 "," $2][$3] } END { for(i in arr) {
  s=""; for(j in arr[i]) s = s (s?",":"") j; print i ",\"" s "\""}}' Input_file
-| City,Sunset,"Ben,Anna"
```

- Declare the comma as input field separator (`-F,`).
- For each line add an entry in array `arr` with keys `$1,$2` and `$3`.
- At the `END` loop over the 2 indexes, concatenate the second (`j`) index in string `s`, separated with commas, print first index (`i`), a comma and string `s` between double quotes.

With any POSIX-compliant `awk` the simplest is probably to sort the input file first, such that all lines with same first and second field are consecutive:

```
sort Input_file | awk -F, '
  function foo() {s=""; for(i in arr) s=s (s?",":"") i
    print key ",\"" s "\""; delete arr}
  {key=$1 "," $2} NR>1 && key!=prv {foo()} {prv=key; arr[$3]} END {foo()}'
```

We use the same principle but with a one-dimension array, and print when the two first fields change (`key!=prv`) or at the `END`, instead of printing everything at the `END`. Note the use of a function (`foo`) to factorize the printing code.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    !a[$0]++{
        b[$1","$2]=(b[$1","$2] ? b[$1","$2]","$3 : $3)
    }
    END{
        for(i in b) print  i,"\""b[i]"\""
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples only please try following code. I am using `uniq` + `awk` combination here.

```
uniq Input_file | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  s1="\""
}
{
  arr[$1 FS $2]=(arr[$1 FS $2]?arr[$1 FS $2] OFS:"") $NF
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,s1 arr[i] s1
  }
}
'
```

***2nd solution:*** Only `awk` solution. Where removing the Duplicates from 1 awk and passing it to main awk then as input.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  s1="\""
}
{
  arr[$1 FS $2]=(arr[$1 FS $2]?arr[$1 FS $2] OFS:"") $NF
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,s1 arr[i] s1
  }
}
' <(awk '!arr[$0]++' Input_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this example:

```
cat file
City,Sunset,Anna
City,Sunrise,Bob
City,Midday,Ellen
City,Sunset,Anna
City,Sunset,Ben
City,Sunset,Ben
City,Sunrise,Ben
```

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -F, -lane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new() }}
h[$F[0..1].join(",")]<<$F[2]
END{puts h.map{|k,v| "#{k},\"#{v.join(",")}\""}}' file
```

Prints:

```
City,Sunset,"Anna,Ben"
City,Sunrise,"Bob,Ben"
City,Midday,"Ellen"
```